# Automake for nested folders - is recursion a must?

Tags: autotools, automake

I have currently the following folder structure in my project:

```
   .
   |-examples
   |-nbis
   |---bozorth3
   |-----include
   |-----src
   |-------bin
   |---------bozorth3
   |-------lib
   |---------bozorth3
   |-zfm20
```

I would like to build it with autotools so I have a file `Makefile.am` with that content:

```
AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign
ACLOCAL_AMFLAGS = -I m4
SUBDIRS = zfm20 examples nbis
```

I have no problems with `zfm20` and `examples`. My question is about folder `nbis`. Here is how `nbis/Makefile.am` looks like:

```
BZ3_LIBDIR = bozorth3/src/lib/bozorth3/
BZ3_BINDIR = bozorth3/src/bin/bozorth3/
BZ3_INCLUDES = bozorth3/include/bozorth3.h bozorth3/include/bz_array.h

lib_LTLIBRARIES = libbozorth.la
libbozorth_la_SOURCES = $(BZ3_INCLUDES) $(BZ3_LIBDIR)bozorth3.c $(BZ3_LIBDIR)bz_alloc.c $(BZ3_LIBDIR)bz_drvrs.c $(BZ3_LIBDIR)bz_gbls.c $(BZ3_LIBDIR)bz_io.c $(BZ3_LIBDIR)bz_sort.c

bin_PROGRAMS = bozorth3
bozorth3_SOURCES = $(BZ3_INCLUDES) $(BZ3_BINDIR)bz3.c $(BZ3_BINDIR)usage.c
bozorth3_LDADD = libbozorth.la
```

But it seem not to work that way. Here is make's output:

```
Making all in nbis
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/pi/git/figure_fingerprint_sensor/nbis'
Makefile:382: .deps/bozorth3/src/bin/bozorth3/bz3.Po: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Makefile:383: .deps/bozorth3/src/bin/bozorth3/usage.Po: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Makefile:384: .deps/bozorth3/src/lib/bozorth3/bozorth3.Plo: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Makefile:385: .deps/bozorth3/src/lib/bozorth3/bz_alloc.Plo: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Makefile:386: .deps/bozorth3/src/lib/bozorth3/bz_drvrs.Plo: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Makefile:387: .deps/bozorth3/src/lib/bozorth3/bz_gbls.Plo: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Makefile:388: .deps/bozorth3/src/lib/bozorth3/bz_io.Plo: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
Makefile:389: .deps/bozorth3/src/lib/bozorth3/bz_sort.Plo: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '.deps/bozorth3/src/lib/bozorth3/bz_sort.Plo'.  Schluss.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/git/figure_fingerprint_sensor/nbis'
Makefile:324: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pi/git/figure_fingerprint_sensor'
Makefile:255: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

If look into folder `.deps` that's what I see:

```
$(BZ3_LIBDIR)bz_sort.Plo
$(BZ3_LIBDIR)bz_io.Plo
$(BZ3_LIBDIR)bz_gbls.Plo
$(BZ3_LIBDIR)bz_drvrs.Plo
$(BZ3_LIBDIR)bz_alloc.Plo
$(BZ3_LIBDIR)bozorth3.Plo
$(BZ3_BINDIR)usage.Po
$(BZ3_BINDIR)bz3.Po
```

Do I really need to have a `Makefile.am` in each nested folder to make it work or did I just messed up the file with variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: this seems to be [a bug in automake itself](https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=13928), and happens whether you use `subdir-objects` or not, so the instructions in this answer are actually wrong. The right option is to stop using variables in the `_SOURCES` list as the list of objects is not otherwise collected correctly.

**Original answer follows.**

I *think* it would be fixed by enabling the `subdir-objects` option for automake.

In `configure.ac`:

```
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([subdir-objects])
```

this way instead of looking for `.deps/bozorth3/src/lib/bozorth3/bz_sort.Plo` it would look for `bozorth3/src/lib/bozorth3/.deps/bz_sort.Plo`.

Comment: I already invoke `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(myproject, 0.1)` in `configure.ac`. Should I call that macro twice?

Comment: No, the invocation with project and version is obsolete and not recommended. You should instead migrate to the new format of using `AC_INIT` to provide project/version and use `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` to provide options.

Comment: I run `make distclean && automake && autoconf && ./configure && make` and still get the same errors. The content of the folder `nbis/.deps` looks also the same. `bozorth3/src/lib/bozorth3/.deps` doesn't get created.

Comment: Then it looks like the bug is worse than I thought and it applies *before* `subdir-objects` is being considered. Stop-gap solution is to avoid using `$(BZ3_LIBDIR)` and `$(BZ3_BINDIR)` in the `_SOURCES` list, that I'm positive would fix it (as non-recursive automake is very much possible and common.)

Comment: That's how my `configure.in` looks like: http://sprunge.us/NdJR Should be ok I think. Looks like I really just need to stop using variables.

Comment: Yeah your script looks good (although you should name it `configure.ac`, the `.in` name is long-obsolete and deprecated.) Actually, it looks like this bug is "known" and fixed (but no new release was made): http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/automake/2015-12/msg00000.html — I still would suggest you not to count on the fix, as people may be using an older automake version anyway.

Comment: The script is actually named `configure.ac`, it was a mistake in my comment. I wouldn't depend on newer version of autotools anyway, because my cross-compile-environment has autotools version 2.68. And I want to work on my project and not rebuild tools all the time :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99548/discussion-between-danny-lo-and-diego-elio-petteno).